# Find probability distribution function of a random process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am trying to figure out how random processes work and I am not sure if I get it right.

There's an example in my book for finding the probability density function and as an extra I am trying to find the probability distribution function.

> I have a random sequence of 0 and 1. They both have the same
>   probability to appear.
>
> I also have two functions
>
> > $x_1(t) = sin (πt)$ for the 0's
> >
> > $x_2(t) = -sin(πt)$ for the 1's
>
> and I need to find the probability distribution function of two random
>   variables for  $t = 0$ and $t = 0.5$

So what I am doing is:

For $t = 0$:

> $x_1(t) = 0$
>
> $x_2(t) = 0$
>
> so my random variable is  $X_0=X(0)$ with a probability $P(X_0) = 1$

and the function should be:

> $F_{x0}(x) = P(X_0\le\ x)=  \begin{cases} 
>        0 & -\infty \leq x\lt 0 \\
>        1 & 0 \leq x\lt \infty     \end{cases}$

For $t = 0.5$:

> $x_1(t) = 1$
>
> $x_2(t) = -1$
>
> so my random variable is  $X_{0.5}=X(0.5)$ with a probability
>   $P(X_{0.5} = 1) = {1 \over 2}$ and $P(X_{0.5} = -1) = {1 \over 2}$

and the function should be:

> $F_{x0.5}(x) = P(X_{0.5}\le\ x)=  \begin{cases} 
>        0 & -\infty \leq x\lt -1 \\
>        1 \over 2\ & -1 \leq x \lt 0\\
>        0 & 0 \leq x \lt 1\\
>        1 & 1 \leq x\lt \infty     \end{cases}$

or since we need to sum up, it should be like this?

> $F_{x0.5}(x) = P(X_{0.5}\le\ x)=  \begin{cases} 
>        0 & -\infty \leq x\lt -1 \\
>        1 \over 2\ & -1 \leq x \lt 0\\
>        1 & 1 \leq x\lt \infty     \end{cases}$

So, is what I am doing correct?

Thanks

Comment: What is meant by, e.g. $"\sin\pi t $ for the 0s"? Generally $t$ denotes a continuous time index (which is suggested by your use of $t=0.5$), and it is unclear how to reconcile that with a necessarily discrete "random sequence."

Comment: The sample space has two possible outcomes, 0 and 1. Every outcome corresponds with one function ($x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$). That's from the Stochastic process theory. Now, the index is continuous but we are interested in discrete values for the specific $t$ given. So for $t=0.5$ we have the two discrete values of $-1$ and $1$.